# gigaspaces gs.bat unable to execute java command

Tags: java, version, gigaspaces

I am trying to execute gigaspaces 9.7.1-ga-b10800 gs-agent.bat (that in turn calls gs.bat) with java 1.7.0_55-b13. 
With echo-ing I traced the issue at the line

```
%COMMAND%
```

from gs.bat.
**Am I missing something? Is there a place I can check if some versions of gigaspaces and java are compatible?**
**The java version 1.6 works fine with this version of gigaspaces.**
I read [this](http://www.gigaspaces.com/EOL):

> Please note that from version 8.0
>   onwards, GigaSpaces XAP will no longer
>   support the Java 1.5 SDK, and will
>   require the use of Java 1.6 SDK or
>   higher. For details about Java 1.4 &
>   1.5 SDK EOL, please refer to the following
>   page:http://java.sun.com/products/archive/eol.policy.html

But it doesn't say anything about java 7 and gigaspaces 9.7.1.

The exact command is ([SOME...] represent some other string):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java"  -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -showversion -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx512m -Dcom.sun.jini.reggie.initialUnicastDiscoveryPort=4169 -Dcom.gs.deploy=[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]/deploy -DagentId= -DgsaServiceID= -DenableDynamicLocators= -Xbootclasspath/p:"[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\xml\*" -cp ;"[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\";"[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\sigar\*;";"[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\\lib\platform\boot\gs-boot.jar"; -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=36000000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=36000000 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=""[SOMETHING]"" -Djava.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi=default -Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=false -Dcom.gs.jini_lus.locators=null -Dcom.gs.jini_lus.groups=[SOMETHING] -Dcom.gs.logging.debug=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file="[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\/config/gs_logging.properties" com.gigaspaces.start.SystemBoot com.gigaspaces.start.services=\"GSA\" gsa.gsc 0 gsa.global.gsm 0 gsa.lus 1
```

The output renders the following:

> java version "1.7.0_55" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
>
> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)
>
> where options include:
>       -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
>       etc.

Best regards,
despot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason java 7 doesn't like this path:

```
\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\
```

when investigating further I found out that JSHOMEDIR is being set to

```
[SOME-PATH-TO-GS-HOME]\tools\groovy\bin\..\..\..\
```

so **in setenv.bat**, I placed a

```
set JSHOMEDIR=%~dp0\..
```

before the line:

```
if "%JSHOMEDIR%" == "" set JSHOMEDIR=%~dp0\..
```

*For some reason setting an (system/user) environment variable didn't change the value of JSHOMEDIR (and yes, I restarted the cmd).*

There is also [the same duplicated post at ask.gigaspaces.org](http://ask.gigaspaces.org/question/25625/gsbat-unable-to-execute-java-command/) with perhaps some additional answers.

Cheers!